# API without authentication

Tags: http, authentication, api-design

I have a problem that should be a very common one, but since I'm new to this field I can't really find what to google for.

I have a server listening for HTTP messages. This server is called by a client that has an API key. At the moment this API key is sent with the request to the server and the server handles the message depending on what API key is provided. This is of course bad because I send the API key in the request.

I don't want the API key to be sent, but how do I, server-side, identify that the client is to be trusted and sure that nobody has stolen the key to make bad requests?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Why is that bad? Sending API keys in the request's headers (as documented [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7235)) is common practice when trying to identify/authenticate(/authorize) your clients.

If you're worried about the stolen API key scenario, steps can be taken towards doubling on that security (like validating the client's domain/URL, as Google does).